# Unit Testing a c# project which uses unmanaged C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing

I have a C# project which interacts with unmanaged C++ through C++/CLI.I have made a unit test which uses all the functionality of unmanaged C++ and returns the status.The unit test when running on base machine has no problem and runs smoothly. When remotely executed the same unit test fails.The software when running on remote machines execute smoothly.

Note: All the dependencies in the remote machine are satisfied

Here is the code

```
[TestMethod()]
public void getstateTest()
{
    bool expected=true;
    bool actual=false;
    try
    {
        GUI.test target = new test();
        expected    = true; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        actual      = target.getstate();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Missing file is : " + exception.FileName);
    }
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

The getstate function is

```
namespace GUI
{
    public class test
    {
        public bool getstate()
        {
            bool chk = false;
            bool result;
            String a = "some path";
            String b = "some path";
            String c = "some path";
            managed  objct;
            objct = new  managed();
            objct.Initialize(a, b, c, chk);
            objct.Execute(); //calls the C++/CLI execute which calls unmanaged C++
            result = objct.Executionresult(); //gets a bool result
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if i made it confusing.Please ask if you need more information. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain "remotely execute"? Is it a remote procedure call?

Comment: Remotely execute means running the unit test under all the registered test agents and not locally...

Comment: @Orsol:the assert of the unit test fails but it should pass as the .exe on the remote machine is executing successfully....

Comment: Look in the visual studio output window while running the tests to see if there are some assemblies being loaded which may not be accessible on the pure test machine.

Comment: @Tormod:as i told in my question itself all the dependencies are satisfied in the pure test machine....

Comment: This is an "it doesn't work" question.  You'll have to do a better job describing what failure looks like.

Comment: There was a file configration.xml which was needed to be present in the same folder as the exe.Hence the software ran successfully on remote machine too.As QTAgent32 runs unit tests hence this configration.xml was required in that folder....This solved the problem

Comment: Using  MessageBox.Show on remote machine is generally not a good idea since someone must click on it to close, it can cause your tests to hang. Use Assert.Fail("Missing file is : " + exception.FileName) instead.